# How do I disable Lenovo's notifications when I press Caps Lock or Num Lock?

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo y50-70 and whenever I press the caps lock or num lock this notification appears and I don't know how to disable it:

[image]

I have been searching all day but I can't a solution that works with windows 10, one solution was to open [regedit > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Widcomm > BTConfig > General > KeyIndication, and change the value of "KeyIndication" from "1" to "0"] but it's already "0". the other was to

- go to Control Panel -> Display -> Screen Resolution.
- Click on Advanced settings.
- Click on the On-Screen Display tab.
- Choose whether to have the indicators show for a few seconds or always show the indicators.

but I can't find On-Screen Display tab in windows 10 so this solution didn't work also, so can anyone help me it's really annoying especially when i'm playing it closes the game to show me the notification.

Comment: This is likely a program launched at startup that was pre-installed on your Lenovo.  If you want to get rid of it, scan though your startup items using `Task Manager`.  Hopefully something will jump out at you.

Comment: maybe add a screenshot of the notification & Startup tab in taskmanager to the question to help us identify the program

Answer (score 5):

No windows version has those icons and windows 10 is one of them. That comes from Lenovo computers. Check with them, not microsoft.

Answer (score 4):

It was Logitech Options app for using a Logitech mouse and a Logitech keyboard (even though I am not using it anymore!). I opened Logitech options by typing it in search

When inside LOGITECH APP press MORE SETTING > NOTIFICATIONS> A LOCK KEY IS PRESSED and deselect it

This caplock notification has been driving me insane for months now!

Comment: This was the source of my issues too.  The setting was a little buried and non-intuitive to find, I added screenshots in my answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1726265/806463

Answer (score 3):

A little late but I just solved this for my self so i'm posting for future visitors.It's not a windows feature. A third party program is responsible for this.

```
Solution: 

1. Task Manager ---> startup -->
2. locate Hkcmd
3. disable it from starting when windows starts
4. restart pc
```

In my case it was Hkcmd. Depending on the brand of your hardware it could be something different but it will be something related to Hot Keys or acronym of that (Hk)

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, this is a Lenovo thing I've been baffled by this. I am including screenshots for Windows 10 Pre-Release updates that are a little different than the above.

Oddly, you won't get the same tabs in this menu by going to the Device Manager. So this should be straight-forward (Especially for upcoming releases).

Hopefully this visual (A bit different) helps anyone that cannot get the above instructions right.

This "feature" drove me nuts. I could not find `Hkcmd` in task manager and this post helped me find how to do this in `Windows Build 1903` (from System Update) -- *I no longer use Windows Insiders Program*

---

**1 (Below)** - Search and Find (I used start menu)
[image: Search and Find this in Start]

---

**2 (Below)** - Click this nearly invisible Link
[image: Click this nearly invisible Link]

---

**3 (Below)** - Go to "Screen Configurations" Tab, then untick "Enable OnScreen Display"

[image: Go to "Screen Configurations" Tab, then untick "Enable OnScreen Display"]

Comment: Hi! When I go through the exact same "path" as you, the last "monitor" screen doesn't look like that at all. Do you know what to do?

Comment: Worked for me when other answers on this thread didn't. Thank you!

Comment: YOU = LIFE-SAVER

Answer (score 1):

On my system, I opened the start menu, then control panel, under Appearance and Personalization, I clicked Adjust screen resolution, then Advanced settings, then in the pop-up window I selected the On Screen Display tab. There, I unchecked the Enable On-screen Display checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add another set of image samples of annoying caps lock indicator:

[image] [image]

This time from **Logi Options+**. This software is installed when you use Logitech mouse. There is an option to turn off the pop up from the settings, *Caps lock, Num lock, Scroll lock and Fn lock notifications*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is the first mention of this I have seen and it fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Caps lock and/or num lock icons displaying permanently on Lenovo laptop screen

I have a Lenovo E530c laptop running on Windows 10. I was experiencing the same problem as many users, judging from the number of on line queries and posts, with the caps lock and/or num lock icons staying permanently on at the bottom centre of the screen (black boxes containing either a white numeral one or a capital letter A).

Several posts suggested going to Control Panel, and clicking on “Display,” then clicking on the “Show the indicator for a few seconds” option. This disables the “Always show the indicator” option that was apparently the root of the problem. I tried this to discover that there was no “Display” option under “Control Panel” on my machine.

I eventually clicked on “Settings”, which resulted in a menu with a “Display” option.  I clicked on the “display adapter properties” link at the very bottom of this page, which led to a series of tabs, one of which is “screen configurations”. This where I found the caps/numlock display options mentioned above.

So if your machine doesn’t have a “Display” heading under Control Panel (like mine) the solution is:

- Click on the “search” icon at the bottom left of the screen
- Type in “Control panel” (both words)
- Click on “Settings”
- Click on “Display”
- Click on “Display adapter settings” at the bottom of the screen
- Click on the “Screen configurations” tab
- Click on the “Show the indicator for a few seconds"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to kill the 'On-Screen Display Application' via task manager, and keep it from coming back by disabling it on the startup tab of task manager (cntrl-shift-esc).