# How can the on-screen indicator for capslock, numlock, etc be removed for an Acer Swift Edge 16?

Tags: capslock, acer

I want to suppress the on-screen indicator that pops up every time I push the capslock key (as well as a few other keys) for an Acer Swift Edge 16.  It's annoying in games.

In the past, I was able to suppress these icons by renaming the icon files in the Acer Quick Access application; however, there seems to have been an update as those files no longer match the appearance of the on-screen indicators.  Turning the "OSD" setting in regedit to "0" also had no effect.  Uninstalling the latest Quick Access program had no effect.  Re-installing the program from Acer's support website, had no effect.  Sometimes, the on-screen display appears to be malformed with it being overly cropped and 50% further left than center, but upon reboot it tends to fix itself.

[image]

**Update:**  Despite Acer Quick Access having been uninstalled, it continues to appear in the Services app (run services.msc) and Task Manager.

In Task Manager, ending the top task causes the indicator to be malformed.  Ending the bottom task causes the indicator to go away.
[image: Task Manager]

In Services.msc, this was set to automatic. Changing to Manual did not change anything after reboot.  Disabling fixed the problem.
[image: Quick Access, still launches when set from Automatic to manual]

Comment: Could be logitech software? https://superuser.com/questions/1512446/how-to-disable-caps-lock-notification-windows-10-for-asus-laptop It's not a Windows thing so the problem is in finding which manufacturer thinks that you absolutely need this kind of "feature": https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/caps-lock-on-screen-display/9268ebed-4702-4bbf-a706-6e318bac8a5e

Comment: Good idea but no logitech software installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been multiple advice given in other posts that
I found, so here is a list.
I don't have Acer so cannot check if any of them works today.

- In folder `C:\Program files\Acer\acer quick access\images`,
  rename `CapsLock_OFF`, `CapsLock_ON`, `NumLock_ON` and `NumLock_OFF`.
  (I assume that this is what you have been doing up to now.)
- In the Services applet, disable the system services of
  "Quick Access Service" and "Quick Access Local Service", then reboot.
- Launch Task Manager, select the task `QAAdmin` and click the
  End Task button to close this task. The task will return on the next
  reboot.

Comment: Thanks but the first bullet (file renaming) is what I mentioned not working anymore in the second part of my question.

Comment: The second and third bullets should have been taken care of by uninstalling Quick Access, but they're still in both the Services app and Task Manager!

Comment: Disabling the Acer Quick Access Service in Services.msc did the trick!  (which is sort of your second bullet)